# Java generics: How to tell Java that a generic type has a method

Tags: java

I am trying to compile the code below:

```
class Good{
  Good(){}
  public void getJoke(){
    System.out.println("Good joke: ...");
  }
}

class Joke<T>
{
    T obj;
    Joke() { this.obj = new T(); } 
    public void getThisJoke() { this.obj.getJoke(); }
}

class GoodJoke extends Joke<Good>
{
    GoodJoke(){
        super();
    }
}

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        GoodJoke j = new GoodJoke(); 
        j.getThisJoke();
    }
}
```

But I am getting the error:

```
T extends Object declared in class Joke
prog.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
    public T getThisJoke() { return this.obj.getJoke(); }
```

How can I tell Java that the generic type 'T' has a method called 'getJoke'?

Comment: `this.obj = new obj();` this is not going to compile

Comment: "*How can I tell Java that the generic type 'T' has a method called 'getJoke'?*" - Throug [bounded type parameters (external link to oracle.com)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)

Comment: How do you expect `Joke<Integer>` to work, when `Integer` does not have a `getJoke` method?

Comment: `this.obj = new T();` won't compile either.

Comment: .... neither is this `new T();`

Comment: `Joke() { this.obj = new T(); }` This won't compile. T can be anything, how do you know it has a no-arg constructor? You don't, and it doesn't necessarily. Hence, not legal

Comment: Sorry for all the mistakes. I though I was only getting the one error mentioned in the post  but there are more issues.

Comment: you cannot cannot be instantiate type parameter 'T'  directly.

Comment: I think I need the unbounded type parameter to be able to do that. Is that right?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce an interface

```
interface Comedian {
    void getJoke();
}
```

Make Good implement it

```
class Good implements Comedian {
    //.. same
```

Make Joke take T as an parameter. There is no way it can instantiate it itself. Add a constraint that T must implement the interface.

```
class Joke<T extends Comedian>
{
    T obj;
    Joke(T obj) { this.obj = obj; }
    public void getThisJoke() { this.obj.getJoke(); }
}
```

Pass Good as an argument to GoodJoke

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    GoodJoke j = new GoodJoke(new Good());
```

Now it compiles https://ideone.com/lDhvdC